# Find near by Bluetooth enabled mobile phones devices using BLE Bluetooth low energy)

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing and android application for find/search nearby Bluetooth enabled (on) mobile phone devices.
so accomplish to my requirement i using the android BLE (Bluetooth low energy) method.
i fallow this android developer documentation [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le)

and i develop and test in my mobile device..
its' working fine with out any errors

but my problem is , it's not find any  Bluetooth enabled mobile phone
i'm using 3 devices oneplus7, samsung j1 and oppo a37f
all devices Bluetooth enabled but nothing show in the scanning list

why is that? is this BLE not support to the discover near by mobile devices(Bluetooth enabled)?

Comment: BLE will only discover what is being "advertised" by the device in the "peripheral role". Are you using an active BLE beacon or other service on the other 3 phones?

Comment: @MorrisonChang no no any service i need to only i need the search Bluetooth enabled devices (mobile phones)

Comment: I would advise using the official samples: https://github.com/android/connectivity-samples  as a reference if there is an error in your code.